# Need to Search a Text Field in Teradata SQL against a list of words and return that word

Tags: sql, search, text, full-text-search, teradata

I am searching a large database for a list of words of varying length between 5-7 characters. 
So far, I have:

```
Select *
  from sometable
 Where upper("Description") like any ("%ABC_123%", "%ABC_124%", "%DE_25%")
```

I would like to also return the word that was found in the query but am stuck on how to do this without duplicating the list of words in a subtr function.

There is probably a much better way of doing this and I'd appreciate some direction.

Comment: I guess the double quote `""%ABC_124%"`is an error, I did not corrected in the edit just in case. If is an error, edit and correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Rob Paller already mentioned there are Regular Expressions in TD14:

```
Select sometable.*,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(Description,'((ABC_)(123|124)|(DE_(25)))') AS match
  from sometable
 Where match <> '';
```

This should be more efficient than hundreds of LIKEs.

Additionally this might be simplified, e.g. if you need ABC_ or DE_ followed by any two or three digits:

```
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(Description,'(ABC_|DE_)([0-9]{2,3})') AS match
```

Comment: +1 for REGEX_SUBSTR example. I have grown very fond of this feature in TD14.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the `POSITION` function and multiple `OR` conditions?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE POSITION('ABC_123' IN UPPER("Description") > 0
   OR POSITION('ABC_124' IN UPPER("Description") > 0
   OR POSITION('DE_25' IN UPPER("Description") > 0;
```

I think either way this is going to be an expensive CPU/IO process on Teradata. I don't know of a native function in Teradata 13.x or older release that will facilitate this. Teradata 14.x (I think 14.10) is supposed to introduce regular expression support natively that may make this an easier solution.

How many list words are you talking about?

What if you use a subquery with the `LIKE` predicate?

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE UPPER("Description") 
 LIKE (SELECT ListWord
       FROM myListWords);
```

You may have to make your list words appear as a pattern in the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE UPPER("Description") 
 LIKE (SELECT '%' || ListWord || '%' AS ListWordPattern
       FROM myListWords);
```

Comment: That was something I was hoping to avoid. I am at 218 words and counting. The plus side is that the list always begins with either ABC_ or DE_ and there are either 2 or 3 numbers after the underscore. But I need to able to return exactly DE_123 or ABC_567. I could skip the list altogether and use a wildcard search...but am stuck with the variable number of characters problem.

Comment: This is an interesting question that has me thinking of other approaches that could possibly make this more reasonable to accomplish in a SET based solution. A cursor would be the easy way out but at a performance/scalability cost.

Comment: Added more details on using a subquery with the LIKE predicate.

Answer (score 1):

4 years later, but anyway... works nicely with LIKE join (and QUALIFY in case of multiple matches)

e.g.

```
SELECT a.orig_pattern
,b.my_keyword
FROM table_with_data a
JOIN table_with_keywords b
ON a.orig_pattern LIKE '%'||b.my_keyword||'%'
QUALIFY row_number() OVER (partition by orig_pattern ORDER by orig_pattern) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the rows you could also use REGEXP:

```
Select *
from sometable
Where Description REGEXP 'ABC_123|ABC_124|DE_25'
```

I haven't been able to figure out your part B, returning the word that was found, unless that word is the only word in the Description field. If it is the only word, you can simply return the contents of the description field.